# Is there a JQuery plugin that does CSS3 round corners?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know you don't need javascript of it...but the script needs to handle "inner elements".

For example, if i stick an image in the div, the round corners are gone in CSS3. Can a JQuery script handle this?

Comment: Just add the border-radius to the image as well (or overflow: hidden to the container), and suddenly they are back ;)

Comment: @Yoshi, because it's dynamic. I don't know if the last children element is an image or a div. I don't know how many images. I need a javascript plugin to "detect" the last children and round them.

Comment: Just updated my comment, use `overflow: hidden`, [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZJJr/)

Comment: if the images you're adding are always the same size, you could also just define the image as a background-image to the div you have rounded corners on.

Comment: THey're not all the same size. Everything is dynamic. I don't even know if the last element is an image :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple solutions for what you problem could be, some are better than the other.

### Elements inside a div need rounded corners.

#### CSS Only

```
div>img {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

#### jQuery applying CSS

```
$("div#id>*").css({
   "border-radius": "10px",
   "-moz-border-radius": "10px",
   "-webkit-border-radius": "10px"
});
```

Or

```
$("div#id").children().css({
   "border-radius": "10px",
   "-moz-border-radius": "10px",
   "-webkit-border-radius": "10px"
});
```

---

### Last child needs rounder corners inside a div

#### jQuery applying CSS

```
$("div#id:last-child").css({
   "border-radius": "10px",
   "-moz-border-radius": "10px",
   "-webkit-border-radius": "10px"
});
```

Or:

```
$("div#id").children(':last').css({
   "border-radius": "10px",
   "-moz-border-radius": "10px",
   "-webkit-border-radius": "10px"
});
```

#### CSS Only

```
div>*:last {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Or

```
div:last-child {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

---

### Box that crops of the corners of what's inside.

#### CSS only

```
div {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What if i only want the last one? Can I do :last?

Comment: overflow hidden "Sort of " works. But it doesn't work for one of my elements

Comment: Nevermind, it doesn't work at all for images.

Comment: How do I know which box affects it? I stuck overflow:hidden; on everything...but not working with images

Comment: That is weird could you send me a jsfiddle or a link of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Try one of the listed solutions above. At least one should work :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS alone, add following class:

```
.round{
 -moz-border-radius:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius:10px;
 border-radius:10px;
}
```

To add the support of rounded corners in IE, you can use [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) (or some other solutions out there)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a jQuery UI custom theme, which generates CSS that includes rounded corners.

[jQuery UI - ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)

Comment: jQuery UI themes control the style of jQuery UI plugins...not arbitrary elements.

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript needed (unless you want to provided rounded borders to browsers which don't support them). You do, however, need to set the border on both the container and the image.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rEq4X/

**HTML**

```
​<div>
    <img src="url" />
​</div>​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
DIV, DIV > IMG{
 -moz-border-radius: 16px;
 border-radius: 16px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a jquery plugin to do what you want, its [here](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)

Although there are some good comments above to say how you'd be better off achieving the effect your after, I think this does answer what you asked.

Still you should use css and graceful degradation for older browsers, rather than add extra processing by using jquery/javascript

Answer (score 0):

Here you go Jquery rounded corner demo

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Comment: It may be the plugin you are looking for http://malsup.github.com/jquery.corner.js